# How to get playstore app verson name and version code android application cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

i have one app in the play store, how can get play store application version name and version code using Cordova, any suggestion appreciated

Comment: parsing the HTML source of the google play page I guess

Comment: how can I achieve this @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: @XarEAhmer this will get you the data about the installed app, not the app in play store. Please read the question carefully before commenting/answering next time

Comment: @MurugananthamS do you want to know how to parse HTML in cordova?

Comment: yes,i want to know playstore app version and current app version ,compare both version if update available i wnt redirect to play store @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: have you tried searching for that? You need around 12 seconds for that.

Comment: yes, I tried to search but I did not get a clear view, I am new to hybrid app development @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: what exactly is a problem for you to parse HTML?

Comment: I didn't have any HTML , I just want to know how to get play store app version, to implement force update @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: that's why I am asking how to do this @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: Ok, you have tried to search, and what was wrong with the solutions you have found during search? Which one you tried? You have to tell that because you are likely going to get the answer you already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check updates, you need to take a platform-specific approach

**iOS Approach**

1. You need to send a request to `https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=BUNDLE_ID`
2. Once you get the result, you can fetch the `version` from `response.data.results[0].version` and then compare it with the local version.
3. Now, if the version is different, you can send the user to the app store using the link `https://itunes.apple.com/app/APP_ID`

**Android Approach**

1. You need to send a request to `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=BUNDLE_ID`
2. Once you get the result, you can extract the version using the snippet below.
3. Now, if the version is different, you can send the user to the app store using the link `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=BUNDLE_ID`

*snippet*

```
var parser = new DOMParser(),
  doc = parser.parseFromString(response.data, 'text/html');
if (doc) {
  var tag = doc.querySelectorAll(".hAyfc .htlgb");
  if (tag && tag[6]) {
    let storeVersion = tag[6].innerText.trim();
    if (local_version != storeVersion) {
      // send to stroe
    }
  }
}
```

> Android approach is rather a DOM-based workaround as we are accessing the
>   index directly using `tag[6].innerText.trim()`, but for iOS, it's a solid one.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=BUNDLE_ID  where i have to send

Comment: you need to replace the *BUNDLE_ID* with your app ID mate

Comment: I am getting an error.. blocked by CORS policy, any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to get the version number of the Play store application, as well as how to implement a force update option. I've tested it, and it is working perfectly.

```
  var your_url =YOUR_PLAY STORE APP_URL;
          $.ajax({
            url: your_url,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(res) {
                let storeVersion =null;
                var doc=null;
                var tag=null;
               var parser = new DOMParser(),
               doc = parser.parseFromString(res, 'text/html');
               if (doc) {
                tag = doc.querySelectorAll(".hAyfc .htlgb");
               if (tag && tag[6]) {
               storeVersion = tag[6].innerText.trim();

               }
               }
               cordova.getAppVersion.getVersionNumber(function(versionNumber){
                var curentVersion = versionNumber;
                var playStoreVersion = tag[6].innerText.trim();
                //alert("loacal version = "+curentVersion+"    "+"playstore version = "+playStoreVersion);
                if(curentVersion<playStoreVersion){
                    navigator.notification.confirm("There is New Version of this application available,Click Upgrade to Update now ?", onConfirm, "Confirmation", "Update,Later");
                }else{
                }
            });
            }
        });
```