# How to ask user or force update Android System WebView and Google Play Services ? [Ionic 4]

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm having android app built using ionic 4 with angular. On some phones users are facing issues with google maps and css styling I have done. This is making UI to appear weird. When user updates Google Play Services and Android System Webview on his/her phone everything works fine. Now I want to show user a message asking them to update this dependencies [google play services, android system webview] or force update them. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: you want to force update your app,using java script

Comment: @MurugananthamS : Not necessary in javascript. May be by using some cordova plugin or some other way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58517113/how-to-get-playstore-app-verson-name-and-version-code-android-application-cordov check here  and add plugin   "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-app-version"

Comment: This will give only latest verison available on playstore.

Comment: That plugin only returns current verison app. Not of other apps

Answer (score -2):

use this plugin 
[here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-version)

import { AppVersion } from '@ionic-native/app-version/ngx';

constructor(private appVersion: AppVersion) { }

...
this.appVersion.getVersionNumber();

check condition

```
use if condition check old version to current version
if(old to current){
console(up to date)
}else{
modal page 
}
```

Comment: I want to update google play services, android system webview not my app